# ShoppingCart ;Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a shopping cart list that I want to loop through, when the item is already in the cart the amount has to be increased, otherwise a new object has to be created.

I know you can't change a list during a loop,
so I tried to work with Tolist() but when I try that he only makes the first object and overwrites when I make the second one.

I don't get this fixed, can somebody help me fix it?

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("Details")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult DetailsPost(int id, DetailsProductViewModel detailsProductViewModel)
    {
        List<ShoppingCart> shoppingCartsList = new List<ShoppingCart>();
        if (HttpContext.Session.Get<IEnumerable<ShoppingCart>>(WC.SessionCart)!=null 
            && HttpContext.Session.Get<IEnumerable<ShoppingCart>>(WC.SessionCart).Count() > 0)
        {
            shoppingCartsList = HttpContext.Session.Get<List<ShoppingCart>>(WC.SessionCart);
            foreach (var item in shoppingCartsList)
            {
                if (item.ProductId == id)
                {
                    item.Aantal += 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    shoppingCartsList.Add(new ShoppingCart { ProductId = id, Aantal = detailsProductViewModel.Product.Aantal });
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            shoppingCartsList.Add(new ShoppingCart { ProductId = id, Aantal = detailsProductViewModel.Product.Aantal });
        }
       
        HttpContext.Session.Set(WC.SessionCart, shoppingCartsList);
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
```

Comment: `foreach (var item in shoppingCartsList.ToList())` although the whole loop looks suspect. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: add the new items to another list, append that list to the original when you're done with the loop. problem solved, case closed.

Comment: to list() I already tried, I have a session of shoppingcart, and when I add something I first want to see if the item is already in the cart. if yes then the number will be increased and if no then I will create a new object.

Comment: You can't add things to a list that you are already looping over, a simple reworking of the logic here should help. Tip: use `shoppingCartsList.Any(sc => sc.ProductId == id)` to determine if the product exists, then you can add/edit. Or use `shoppingCartsList.SingleOrDefault(sc => sc.ProductId == id)` and check for null.

Answer (score 1):

you don't need a loop. just try to find the item in the list. if found, increase amount, if not create new one.

```
...//also check your shoppingCartsList is null or not
var product = shoppingCartsList.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.ProductId == id);
if(product == null)
{
 shoppingCartsList.Add(new ShoppingCart { ProductId = id, Aantal = detailsProductViewModel.Product.Aantal });
}
else
{
   product.Aantal++;
}

HttpContext.Session.Set(WC.SessionCart, shoppingCartsList);
```

Comment: thanks, that makes more sense indeed. it solved the problem :)